# Can't access new NGINX server with local Host Entry on MAC OSX

Tags: macos, nginx, host

I'm trying to move a static HTML website to a server that is also running a PHP site but I'm getting the following error when I try to access the site after entering my local host entry:

> This site can’t be reached
>
> www.example.com’s server DNS address could not be found.

This is my configuration file */etc/nginx/sites-available*:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    server_name www.example.com example.com;

    autoindex off;
    index index.html index.php;

    root /var/www/example/html;
    access_log /var/www/example/logs/access.log;
    error_log /var/www/example/error.log;
}
```

I have also ran these commands:

```
sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/example /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
sudo service nginx restart
```

And I have added a host entry on my local machine to */etc/hosts*
??.???.??.??        www.example.com
??.???.??.??        example.com

And of course I have the website's files located at */var/www/example/html* with full 777 permissions (for now) and www-data:www-data ownership.

**UPDATE**

I'm getting the same error in Firefox, and when I try pinging the site I get the following, it just seems to be timing out.

```
ping www.example.com
PING www.example.com (??.???.??.??): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8
Request timeout for icmp_seq 9
Request timeout for icmp_seq 10
Request timeout for icmp_seq 11
Request timeout for icmp_seq 12
Request timeout for icmp_seq 13
Request timeout for icmp_seq 14
Request timeout for icmp_seq 15
Request timeout for icmp_seq 16
Request timeout for icmp_seq 17
Request timeout for icmp_seq 18
Request timeout for icmp_seq 19
Request timeout for icmp_seq 20
Request timeout for icmp_seq 21
Request timeout for icmp_seq 22
Request timeout for icmp_seq 23
Request timeout for icmp_seq 24
Request timeout for icmp_seq 25
Request timeout for icmp_seq 26
Request timeout for icmp_seq 27
Request timeout for icmp_seq 28
Request timeout for icmp_seq 29
Request timeout for icmp_seq 30
Request timeout for icmp_seq 31
Request timeout for icmp_seq 32
Request timeout for icmp_seq 33
Request timeout for icmp_seq 34
Request timeout for icmp_seq 35
Request timeout for icmp_seq 36
Request timeout for icmp_seq 37
Request timeout for icmp_seq 38
Request timeout for icmp_seq 39
Request timeout for icmp_seq 40
Request timeout for icmp_seq 41
Request timeout for icmp_seq 42
Request timeout for icmp_seq 43
Request timeout for icmp_seq 44
Request timeout for icmp_seq 45
Request timeout for icmp_seq 46
# still going
```

My Other host entries are working.

Comment: *www.example.com’s server DNS address could not be found* — That's a DNS error. Not an HTTP error. It has nothing to do with nginx.

Answer (score 0):

OK - just to be clear, this isn't a problem with your Nginx setup.  The error is coming from your web browser, and it's saying it doesn't know how to go about trying to talk to the web server.

You don't say what web browser you're using, but I'm guessing it's Chrome from the error message.  It should honour the entry which you've put in /etc/hosts, but it seems it isn't doing.

Two suggestions:

1) Test your entry in /etc/hosts by typing:

```
ping www.example.com
```

2) Try a different web browser, or completely re-start Chrome.

Note that the error message is in a sense correct - you haven't set up a DNS entry for your server so it's reasonable that the browser can't find it.  The entry in /etc/hosts should be used first though - you are sure you've put it in /etc/hosts on the machine running the web browser aren't you?

Comment: thanks I've tried in FireFox and get the same error.  And I just keep getting `Request timeout for icmp_seq` when I try pinging the site.  What else should I try?  My other host entries work.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how or why this worked but when I did the following it started working.

First I changed the NGINX config to use the IP address as the server name so I could check if it worked without using a host entry:

```
# server_name www.example.com;
server_name ??.???.??.??;

autoindex off;
#index index.php index.html;
index index.html;
```

And it then worked when I went to http://??.???.??.??.

I was convinced it was just an issue with my local host entry then, but when I changed the server name back to `server_name www.example.com;` it worked when I went to http://www.example.com.

Just thought I would share this if it could be of any help to someone.